# Book similar to Berkeley Problems in Mathematics

Tags: reference-request

The book Berkeley Problems in Mathematics was a wonderful source of interesting, some different and challenging problems for (under)graduate students.

However, for a long time, I did not find  see any changes in the printing of the book: it contains problems up to Fall $2003$.

Can one suggest some **recent books of similar type**, which contain (Under)Graduate Problems in Mathematics from various branches such as Algebra, Analysis, Topology, Differential equations etc., which are collected from an exam for Ph.D. program in a prestigious university or institute?

Comment: The Art of Problem Solving is not enough? https://artofproblemsolving.com/

Comment: @markvs:  AoPS seems to be mainly for (advanced) high school students, not (under)graduates

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: AOPS contains a lot of different problems, including some problems of (under) graduate level. For example, Putnam exams, https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/William_Lowell_Putnam_Mathematical_Competition

Answer (score 10):

Disclosure: I am one of the authors of the BPM.

At the time we wrote the book, end of the 80s, there was no similar material. There was a lot of problems book in Mathematics, but they fell on typically 3 categories:

- **Books on problem solving**: George Polya - [How To Solve It](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069116407X), etc...
- **Books on specific areas**: Like the ones in the series [Problem Books in Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KKPXD9K) from Springer, that our book was later part of.
- **Books on Olympic problems**: [The Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CWR4RE4) by Ken Williams, [The Stanford Mathematics Problem Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CWR50OU), ...

In fact one source of inspiration in terms of general material was a book on the [Princeton Physics Prelims](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691024493/princeton-problems-in-physics-with-solutions):

[image: Physics Prelim Book]

which was a generalist book.

The only other generalist book I know is: [Problems and Solutions in Mathematics](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/7741#t=aboutBook) by Ta-Tsien Li et al.

[image: Problems and Solutions in Mathematics]

Since then several publishers (Dover, AMS, Springer, World Scientific, ...) have published some nice problems books and series, among the remarkable are Masayoshi Hata's collection of problems in real analysis:

[image: Masayoshi Hata's collection of problems in real analysis]

The 4th Edition of our book is coming out this Fall (2023) and -- because of size -- may be split into several books - by subject.

Comment: Have the 4th edition of your legendary book been released?